# Ionic 3 - CLI Generate não faz o arquivo module

Tags: ionic

Olá! Quando eu utilizo o comando "*ionic g page Exemplo*", o mesmo cria apenas três arquivos, ao invés de 4.

```
-exemplo.html
-exemplo.scss
-exemplo.ts
```

Porém, eu acredito precisar do *exemplo.module.ts* pois estou recebendo o seguinte erro na modal: Uncaught (in promise) error: invalid link: nomeDaPagina.

Comment: Parece que tiraram https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/pull/12347 . Como todas as páginas do meu projeto já estavam usando o module.ts eu crio uma nova toda vez que faço uma nova página. Não sei qual motivo deles terem tirado

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente isso foi retirado do ionic temporariamente. Existe uma solução para que possa utilizar esse comportamento de criação do *.module.ts*.

Para voltar a criar o arquivo você tem a possibilidade de fazer o downgrade dos scripts do app. Para isso faça da seguinte maneira:

- Abra o arquivo *"package.json"* do seu projeto. Ele está na raiz do projeto Ionic.
- Dentro dele, busque a propriedade *"devDependencies"* do json e altere o `"@ionic/app-scripts": "2.0.2"` deixando com a versão `"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7"`.
- Apague a pasta "node_modules" do projeto.
- Execute o comando `npm install`.
- Após executar o comando para gerar a nova Page o .module.ts estará criado dentro da pasta juntamente com os demais arquivos.

**Obs:** Este procedimento é para utilizar uma versão anterior de scripts onde a criação dos modules ainda estava em funcionamento. Na nova versão "2.0.2" esta opção não está funcionando. Logo fica a seu critério a utilização deste passo a passo.